# any package for zooming and zoom out which is compatible with angular 14

Tags: angular, npm, zooming

Is there any package for zoom in and zoom out for angular 14, I have tried ngx-image-zoom in this it is showing the error of
node_modules/ngx-image-zoom/lib/ngx-image-zoom.component.d.ts:124:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

I have tried npm i ngx-image-zoom this package